# how to make python wait untill for a specific hotkey imput

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard

I've been trying to find a way for python to wait after a hotkey ('ctrl+0') is pressed and than continue after the same hotkey is pressed again. I'm using the package keyboard and I've been trying with this method:

```
if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl+0'):
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.wait('ctrl+0')
```

For some reason, the code works when the second hotkey is different from the first one, but that's not what I'm aiming for.

Comment: is that all of the code? are you running it in a loop?

Comment: the rest of the code are just other elif's and yes it's running in loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work

```
if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl+0'):
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.wait('ctrl+0',suppress=True)
```